# Tons of direct views in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

For months i'm suspecting that google analytics doesn't track referers right. There is a ridiculous amount of direct views, and I know for sure that some people who get from a regular link are counted as direct.

Why is this happening to me?

How to debug/resolve this issue?

I'm clueless...

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you mean by a "ridiculous amount"? Some context would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone is interested, it has come to my knowledge fairly late that when a site with ssl referer to my site (which isn't ssl) it displays it as direct view